# Can I modify an OpenGL raster directly before it is rendered to the graphics context?

Tags: c, opengl

I am still learning basics of OpenGL and one thing is really bothering me; Can I modify the resulting raster directly, before it is rendered to the underlying graphics context?

For example, I have a simple demo program that prints 3 white F bitmaps on a black background:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

GLubyte rasters[24] = {
    0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00,
    0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00,
    0xff, 0xc0, 0xff, 0xc0
};

void init(void)
{
   glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
   glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

void display(void)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   glRasterPos2i (20, 20);
   glBitmap (10, 12, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, rasters);
   glBitmap (10, 12, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, rasters);
   glBitmap (10, 12, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, rasters);
   glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho (0, w, 0, h, -1.0, 1.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch (key) {
   case 27:
       exit(0);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize(100, 100);
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
   init();
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutMainLoop();
   return 0;
}
```

Can I intercept the OpenGL pipeline to modify the resulting raster to put a colored pixel at a specific coordinate directly(e.g. red pixel at 9, 9), before it is drawn without having to go through explicitly calling glBitmap and passing a silly buffer to it before it is rendered to the underlying graphics context?

Comment: This is really legacy GL use. It might work, or not. But you really should not. GL is a 3D Api first. It's no good for pixel drawing. Even for bitmap blits you should use textures.

Comment: @starmole what do you mean? I should use something else instead of glBitmap?

Comment: Take a look at shaders (GLSL). There is a stage programme, called fragment shader which allows you to modify each pixel on screen before actually passing it to the ctx to render.

Comment: @Dmitry yes. Draw a rectangle with a texture. A good exercise would be to try to do what you want using only OpenGL:ES2.